# Web Deployment Project missing in ASP.Net Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, precompiled

I have installed the web deployment project on VS 2005.

When i click on my Web Site context menu i see the  "Add Deployment Project", but when i click on my Web Application Project i don't see it.

I have done the task "devenv /setup" in my computer run, but it didn't help.
How can i see the Add Web Deployment Project in my VS 2005 SP1 when i click on Web Application?
When i installed the Web Deployment Project i have see it in my Web Site context menu, but when i migrate my Web Site to Web Application it disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

It should be at the top level of your solution.  However, note that it won't have a plus sign to the left of it like most other projects do.

You might want to double-check that the version of web deployment projects you're using works with VS 2005.